# CustomValidator in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I am created one customvalidator for checking the min salary and max salary. What I did means I get minsalary value in one textbox and maxsalary in one textbax. if the maxsalary is less than minsalary means it'll display some error message.

Some of the Testcase
min-40 max-65 -Noerror
min-40 max-400-Error

Actually what It doing means it compare the min salary first digit with maxsalary first digit and second digit likewise it checking.if it's less than means it'll automatically displayed the error message. Can any one please help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use a CompareValidator instead of a customvalidator ?
Like so:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMaxSal" Operator="LessThan" ControlToCompare="txtMinSal" Type="Integer" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Error Text here"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: What I want to give in the Text place

Comment: You can leave ' Text="*" ' out of it if you want, then the errormessage will come after the element you placed it.
If you have other fields in your form you check you can summarize all errors in a ValidationSummary attribute

Comment: <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtSalaryMax" Operator="LessThan"
         ControlToCompare="txtSalaryMin" Type="Integer" 
         Text="max salary less than minsalary" ErrorMessage="Error Text here">
         </asp:CompareValidator>

Comment: May there be a possibility to input salaries under 0 ?
otherwhise you can add another compareValidator to the minSalary textbox:
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSalaryMin" Operator="LessThan" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Salary has to be above 0"></asp:CompareValidator>

Answer (score 0):

Change the text to numbers and then compare them using > or <.  You can't compare numbers alphabetically which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I added ajaxtoolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender for that text box . but i'm facing the same problem